# Unable to create a system restore in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, system-restore

When I'm trying to create a system restore in Windows Vista, I get the below error. How can I solve this?

[image: Error photo showing the dialogue boxes]

Comment: Why do you have the Recovery partition set to be a location for recovery points?  I doubt that partition is very large.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why Solve System Restore Catastrophic Failure 0X8000ffff happen, including having malware, spyware, or programs not installing properly. You can have all kinds of system conflicts, registry errors, and Active X errors. Reimage specializes in Windows repair. I find a repair tool and you could try it.
http://repairerrors.net/solve-system-restore-catastrophic-failure-0x8000ffff.html
Also please backup important data before make any changes.